# How to handle UIScrollView in a UITableView with multiple text fields

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, ios6, ios7

I am new to iOS programming.
My confusion is on one `UIView`. I am adding two `UITableView`s
For second `TableView` I am using custom TableView Cells. On that TableViewCell I am adding TextFields.
First table Views also I have text fields. 
Now On The View I should Use `UIScrollView`. How can I Handle `Scroll View` here when I click on all these text Fields.

Comment: share some code, and maybe a couple of screenshots(if you're working with storyboard). it would help us help you.

Comment: Unclear. You probably need to explain what you mean by "handle scroll view". Just guessing at your meaning, you might also want to search on embedding UITableViews inside UIScrollViews.